# extracting the first element of a tuple via list comprehension in haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, list-comprehension

I tried to extract the first element of a tuple in a list of tuples in haskell via list comprehension but somehow it just outputs the first one and then stops, so I decided to do it via recursion which looked like this:

```
tuples :: (Ord a, Ord b) => [(a, b)] -> [a]
tuples [] = []
tuples ((x,y):xs) = x : tuples xs
```

Now, while this works I would like to know how to do the same thing via list comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use pattern matching in the list comprehension, with:

```
tuples :: [(a, b)] -> [a]
tuples xs = [ x | (x, _) <- xs ]
```

But likely the simplest way is just to work with [**`fst :: (a, b) -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fst):

```
tuples :: [(a, b)] -> [a]
tuples = map fst
```

The typeconstraints for `(Ord a, Ord b)` are *not* necessary: nowhere do we use a function defined for types that are members of the `Ord` typeclass.

Comment: Just for fun: `do (x, _) <- xs; pure x`